# Google Apps: Not receiving email from same domain sent by PHP mail()

Tags: php, sendmail, google-apps

For testing the email sent by PHP mail() I have the following script called phpmail.php

```
<?php

$to      = "david@domain.com david@gmail.com david@otherdomain.com";
$header  = "From: noreply@domain.com";
$subject = "Testing PHP email from domain.com";
$body    = "This is sent form the server.";

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)) {
    echo("Message successfully sent!");
} else {
    echo("Message delivery failed...");
}

?>
```

it sends to 3 email addresses:

1. david@domain.com (Google Apps)
2. david@gmail.com (standard Gmail)
3. david@otherdomain.com (Also Google Apps)

the script is run from the server hosting the "domain.com" website. While the same message is received by emails 2. and 3., it's not by 1. which is the same domain where PHP was executed.

Is there something I need to change from the server to make it work? Thank you.

Edit: The MX is setup correctly using instructions from

https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125?hl=en

I have another server using this settings and it's working correctly. For some reason, it's not working with this server. I believe (fuzzy memory) it worked some time ago.

Comment: I believe your `$to` e-mail addresses need to be comma separated: `david@domain.com, david@gmail.com` .  I would also recommend looking into the `-f` parameter in the [additional_parameters for mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: @cale_b It actually works with or without commas.

Comment: Glad it works.  [The docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) specify a comma.  Hope it continues to work without.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by changing the network hostname (it was same as the Google Apps) to something else following instruction from this site:

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/centos-hostname-change

Comment: Glad you solved it! Turns out it was a DNS-ish issue in the end ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the first Google Apps domain on the same domain as the website is hosted? It is likely that your server is configured to recognize 'internal' mail. If this is the case, the mail is delivered to the local mailserver instead of the Google Apps mailserver.

The solution is to configure the DNS (specifically MX) records of your (web) server to point to Google Apps. This can be done easily if you have a control panel like DirectAdmin or Plesk. If not, Google specific instructions for your setup.

Comment: Yes, MX is configured correctly following this instruction https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125?hl=en I actually have another site domain using Google Apps, it's working fine.

Comment: Alright, have you checked the spam folder on the Google Apps mailbox? And are you saying the website is hosted at a different domain than the mail domain?

Comment: It's not in the spam. As stated, the script that is run form the website using the same domain that uses Google Apps isn't receiving the email, even with DNS MX set correctly, thanks.